# Icon does not change when div is collapsed and expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Once the button or the "caret-down" icon is clicked, it will expand and the content will be shown. At the same time, the icon in the button will change to "minus" icon but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code.

```js
 $('#demo').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
      var getID = $(this).attr("id");
      getID = $("#toggle-" + getID);
      $(getID).toggleClass("fa-caret-down fa-minus")
    });

    $('#demo').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
      var getID = $(this).attr("id");
      getID = $("#toggle-" + getID);
      $(getID).toggleClass("fa-minus fa-caret-down");
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/register-dev.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/activity-registration.css">

  
   <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
 <button class="btn btn-light btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Detail
  <span><i id="toggle-demo" class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</button>
     </div> 
      </div> 
         </div>
      <div id="demo" class="collapse in">Some dummy text in here.</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Snippet**

I would prefer to do it with `IDs`. Give an id `i` tag. I know there are many ways to do. But with the solution below. you will get good performance. because it will target the id not scanning the element from DOM

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  var getID = $(this).attr("id");
  getID = $("#toggle-" + getID);
  $(getID).toggleClass("fa-caret-down fa-minus")
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  var getID = $(this).attr("id");
  getID = $("#toggle-" + getID);
  $(getID).toggleClass("fa-minus fa-caret-down");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-light btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Detail
        <span><i id="toggle-demo" class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="demo" class="col collapse in">Some dummy text in here.</div>
<br>
<div class="col">
  <button class="btn btn-light btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Detail
    <span><i id="toggle-demo2" class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="demo2" class="col collapse in">Some dummy text in here.</div>
```

Comment: Im not sure why mine is not working here. Here's the updated code I just posted. @Sodhi saab

Comment: I would recommend you to upload your code somewhere like github or jsfiddle. Then I can have look.

Comment: if you need help. you can send me email too. Find it from profile page. I would like to help New bees free.

Comment: Here's the link. https://jsfiddle.net/h8a7LpLn/ 

When I click on the 2nd button, it was the 1st button that expand and collapse instead. @Sodhi saab

Comment: @SabrinaSaid please check the snippet now. ID always should be unique. and your target herf was also same for both collapses.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `button` isnt a parent of the `div` you cant use `parent()` method, and you are doing wrong removing and adding same class at the same line, you also can work with `toggleClass()`. The proper way to do it would be next:

```js
$('#demo').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   console.log("Opened")
   $('button[data-target="#demo"] > span > i.fa').toggleClass("fa-caret-down fa-minus")
});

$('#demo').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   console.log("Closed")
   $('button[data-target="#demo"] > span > i.fa').toggleClass("fa-minus fa-caret-down")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button class="btn btn-light btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
    Detail
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">Some dummy text in here.</div>
```

> **Note:** You also can use next selector in combination with `find()` method if you prefer:

```
$('button[data-target="#demo"]').find("i.fa").toggleClass("fa-caret-down fa-minus")
```

Comment: what if I have multiple button with the same function? @SilverSurfer

Comment: You mean multiple button to open div with id=demo?

Comment: It will works fine, but changing the icons for all buttons when you clicked one because are associated with the div.

Comment: Im not sure why mine is not working here. I just updated on my post @SilverSurfer